# My scss file is not converting into css file

Tags: html, css, sass

I am making a simple scss demo application. In which i am using sass as the styling css preprocessor for my app. But after importing all the scss files and running the command on CLI. My file is not converting into css.

This is package.json file

```
"scripts": {
"compile": "node-sass css/main.scss css/main.css --watch",
"start": "live-server"
}
```

And in the terminal i am running following command:

```
npm run compile
npm run start
```

in main.scss file i have imported all my scss files. And this command file convert it into css file. But after running above two commands it is not working.
I am adding main.scss file for the reference.

```
@import "variables";
@import "base";
@import "buttons";
@import "content";
```

Comment: What do you get if you manually run: `node-sass css/main.scss css/main.css --watch`

Comment: 'node-sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you install node-sass? https://github.com/sass/node-sass

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0"
  },

Comment: What error do you receive if you run: `npm install node-sass`

Comment: Hi added the answer after doing some changes. Please refer to it

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the dev dependencies name dart-sass which is deprecated and now it is sass.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.34.1"
  }
```

After installing changed the scripts to

```
"scripts": {
"compile:sass": "sass scss:assets/css",
"start": "live-server"
```

},

After running command npm run compile:sass, my sass file converted into css file.